# Performance of CSS regex id selector vs class selector

Tags: html, css, performance, css-selectors

Let's say I have on page 2000 elements. I want to inject into this page elements (banners) from custom module. This module's css file has 300+ css selectors, each selector needs to have unique dynamic prefix to avoid conflicts with other modules inside the same page. I can not use 1 unique id selector because more banners can be loaded, so I need to use something like this:

```
<div id="company_banner14"></div>
<div id="company_banner15"></div>
div[id^='company_banner']{

}
```

or

```
<div id="company_banner14" class="company_banner"></div>
<div id="company_banner15" class="company_banner"></div>
.company_banner{

}
```

What is better from performance view? Is using regex selector bad practice, would 300 regex selectors make any visible performance impact?

Comment: Good question, i'm interested in that also.

Comment: What's the point of having the class attribute if you're not going to use class selectors? Especially when you're talking performance. It just seems... odd.

Comment: You are right, this was my mistake, I modified the question.

Comment: Regular expression matching is slower than simple class-based matching.
https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-selectors-that-look-like-regular-expressions

Comment: I wish there was some information on the performance impact

Answer (score -1):

After looking at what you need is have a custom CSS for all elements. There are some points that should be kept in mind for this query.

1. **Using Inline CSS-**  I think inline CSS is the best solution if you are not using long CSS for one element. It saves very valuable amount of code to your page if your loop too many elements. For example, `<div id="company_banner15" class="company_banner" style="Width:x; height:y;"></div>`
2. **Using CSS Classes-** It is the alternate way for Inline CSS but not as code saver as Inline CSS. if your using same type of style to all elements it is accurate not not if your using different type of style in loop.

Hope these suggestion will guide you. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: There will be 300 different selectors because each div will have further elements. Using inline css for 300+ elements won't be ok. Question is just if it is better to use class selector or id regex selectors for those 300 elements inside. Each element inside needs to have defined parent selector to avoid any conflicts.